# How to make sure that the method body code is not changed

Tags: maven, junit

Let say there is a method `V1Archiver`.

Now we want to make sure that during development somebody should not modify this method at all, or if modified need to get it reviewed by two different departments.

Possible ways in my mind:

1. Make sure before any release that there is no diff for this method or class, but this require manual check plus not salable.
2. Write JUnit test case which somehow get the method body as a string and calculate the hash and compare it with the predefined hash. But how to write such JUnit test case?
3. Is there some maven plugin which could help me?

Is there any better strategy to achieve my use case?

Comment: A stern comment and a good culture of code review of all changes? Not all solutions have to be technical...

Comment: I think VCS (e.g. Git) may help to achieve this.

Comment: Deny write rights for all Dev users in file system?

Comment: I also find your question to be much too broad. You see: there are many many solutions to such things; and no "technical" best stands out here; and as Jon as mentioned, you can even look for non-technical solutions. Besides: I am even worried about this requirement of yours. You see, all code is subject to change. What you are actually looking for is to make sure that only certain people will make changes here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement of all projects. You need to find a layer/module/component which has a separate functionality and maintain in separately.

You must create jar file of such code which will only have class files. Then include in your project and maintain in separate branch.